# Is there a java library to synthetize a french voice (TTS)?

Tags: java, text-to-speech

I'm trying to develop a program in which I want to put a text-to-speech in french!
I looked for FreeTTS but it doesn't work in French.

Also I can't use a web service as Google Tranlate because my application does not access the Internet.

Thanks

Comment: i think ivona works in french, but i dont think is free

Comment: Thank you. Yes it's not free and of course I want a free library !

Comment: what about eSpeak? http://espeak.sourceforge.net/

Comment: eSpeak is not a java library but an independent program ! :/

Answer (score 2):

Too late for the OP but anyway.

A couple of month ago I've looked for the same library but for English language (with simple API, something like `new Speech(Lang.EN).say("Hello, World!")...`). And I've figured out that there are not free "pure Java" libraries for text-to-speech task. For that time I've got satisfied with **Festival** (I implemented simple wrapper that interacts with the program just via command line interface).

So try to search not for Java TTS library, but for *binding/frontend/wrapper* for TTS systems like **Festival**, **eSpeak**, **OpenMary**, etc. Probably such *binding/frontend/wrapper* will come with a bunch of jars, native libraries and resource files for each supported platform (so you can just link them with your project, don't need to install anything).

As it meant that third-party binding are well tested and documented you will don't worry how it works inside. From Java point of view you will see a simple API.